# Why is Django showing a KeyError?

Tags: python, django

I've been looking at the Django docs for an example on how to add CSS classes to model form inputs. When I use the solution, though, Django raises a KeyError, and I can't really pinpoint the source, because the line of code the debug screen shows is a completely irrelevant CSS class in the template.

The solution:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['title', 'content', 'category'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['content'].widget.attrs.update(size='100', height='50')
```

The error message:

```
KeyError at /new/

('title', 'content', 'category')

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/new/
Django Version:     2.1.7
Exception Type:     KeyError
Exception Value:    

('title', 'content', 'category')

Exception Location:     /home/bob/python-virtualenv/blog/bin/blog/posts/forms.py in __init__, line 11
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use multiple keys in this way:

```
self.fields['title', 'content', 'category']
```

You will have to look them up separately:

```
self.fields['title']
self.fields['content']
...
```

Or in your code:

```
for key in ['title', 'content', 'category']:
    self.fields[key].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

Note that it is allowed to use a tuple as key in a dictionary in Python:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> a['some','tuple'] = 'value'
>>> a
{('some', 'tuple'): 'value'}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!